# creating shortcuts in Mac OSX at command line

Tags: bash, alias

I run a MacBook Pro with yosemite OSX.  I'm trying to create shortcuts to go to certain directories, run script files, etc.  This is my first attempt at creating shortcuts/aliases.  I'm asking in this forum because when I type

```
cd ~
ls -la
```

I get a list of files/folders like `.bash_profile` and `.bash_history` (but no .bashrc yet).

Here is the content I put in the file:

```
alias run-vagrant = "cd ~/vagrant-dev/v104 && vagrant up"
```

But when i enter `run-vagrant` on command line I get a message

```
-bash: run-vagrant: command not found
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Apart from the error is the syntax of the `alias` command (there should be no spaces around `=`), it is unclear what file you are adding this command into. Bash is by default started as a login shell on macOS, so `.bash_profile` will be used. I'm voting to close this as unclear until such time that it is clarified.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this.  Use .bash_profile vs. .bashrc

Additionally, you may need to type in

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

to reload.

Also, here are two helpful links I found:

https://www.moncefbelyamani.com/create-aliases-in-bash-profile-to-assign-shortcuts-for-common-terminal-commands/
and this - https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/891 - but don't follow the advice on .bashrc (I guess - as this didn't work for me) - use .bash_profile instead.

Also, look at the comments on the 2nd link - requiring `.bash_aliases` in `.bash_profile` is a more elegant way to roll..